# TBXML with NSData in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, tbxml

I have a URL that returns a pretty flat XML file: `<entries><title>val1</title><author>Bob</author></entries>` The code runs ok:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somesite.php?qid=%d", __inum];
NSLog(@"urlString = %@", urlString);
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSData * myData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", myData);

TBXML *sourceXML = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLData:myData error:nil];

TBXMLElement *rootElement = sourceXML.rootXMLElement;

if (rootElement) {

    NSLog(@"Root element found...");

TBXMLElement *qaElement1 = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:rootElement];
if (qaElement1) {
    NSString *idAttribute = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"title" forElement:qaElement1];
    NSLog(@"Got to the 1st call for idAttribute... %@", idAttribute);
}
else { NSLog(@"There is no value for title..."); }

}

else { NSLog(@"Root element must be null..."); }
```

}

It finds the root element and gets to the call for valueOfAttribute:@"title" but the value is always (null).

So my question: do I have to do something to convert the NSData back to man readable (I was under the impression TBXML gave that option to work with the NSData and did the calculation). If not, what is the call to create (and then use) an NSString in UTF8 from 'myData'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the call to create (and then use) an NSString in UTF8 from 'myData'?

use [`initWithData:encoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithData:encoding:)

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or [`stringWithUTF8String:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithUTF8String:) if you know `myData` is null-terminated UTF8 string

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[myData bytes]];
```

---

Do *not* ignore error.

```
NSError *error = nil;
TBXML *sourceXML = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLData:myData error:&error];
if (error) {
     // handle it, at least log it
}
```

Comment: And then use TBXML... initWithXMLString:str...?

Comment: @user3741598 Yes. and you can log the XML string to make sure it is what you expected.

Comment: Brian, that worked and I can read my XML file - but still throwing the (null) for idAttribute. That should be the val inside <title>val</title>, correct? I will keep poking around....

Comment: I never used tbxml. but attribute `title` is `<Element title='val' />`

Comment: I tried your format - didn't even throw (null). Gave the error that means it didn't find the root. Strange.

Comment: your code is for `<entries><title title='val' /></entries>`

Comment: Brian, no. But check this: I added NSString * description = [TBXML textForElement:qaElement1]; and this returned the val1 - I think my XML file is too flat. So I think I'm good to go. Accepting your answer since it got me over the hump. Thanks.